# Quando utilizar console.clear?

Tags: javascript

Estava mexendo no meu website e instalei um plugin, infelizmente o mesmo não carregava de acordo com a página, dando vários avisos no console, para cada produto um aviso, ou seja, mais de 100 avisos ( avisos, não erros ), utilizei o console.clear para eliminar esses avisos. 
Tem algum problema ao fazer isso?
Quando devo utilizar console.clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `console.clear` é usado para limpar as mensagens do console, as quais geralmente escritas com `console.log`.

Visa facilitar a leitura das  informações do LOG em ambiente de desenvolvimento/teste, na depuração de códigos, quando há muita coisa desnecessária, limpamos para depois escrever as novas informações.

Não há nenhum problema em limpar.

Só tenha cuidado para que o `console.clear` não atrapalhe quando você quiser debugar alguma coisa. Ou seja, não limpe mensagens que você queira ver.